# Homeomorphism between evenly spaced integer topology and the rationals

Tags: gn.general-topology

The [evenly spaced integer topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evenly_spaced_integer_topology) is countable, metrizable, and has no isolated points, and hence is homeomorphic to the rationals with the order topology. But what is an explicit construction for this homeomorphism?

This question was asked on MSE but got no answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1849271/52694

Comment: You refer to a certain theorem asserting that such spaces are homeomorphic. Have you read the proof of this theorem?